# How to get the sub-links inside a post using get_children on loop in homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a WordPress 4.4 in my homepage I show all posts in grids and inside posts ,I placed around 3 to 5 links `<a>`.

The thing is I want to show count of all the sub-links which is inside posts in the homepage.

I tried using the following code, but it fetches only attachments but mine is links. Please help me with it.

```
<?php 
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
$nbImg = count($attachments);
echo $nbImg.'&nbsp; Files';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer to my question, I have created a common category  for each sub-links in a post and called it in the front like this...

Hope this helps to someone who is searching.. :)

```
<?php
$abc = get_the_category();
foreach(get_the_category() as $category) 
{} 
$zz = array(
'category_slug' => $abc[0]->category_nicename
);
$tt = sdm_handle_for_test($zz);
echo count($tt).' Files';
?>
```